# Find a base of the image of an inverse linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a linear map $f:U \to W$. If we are given $V \subset W$, how can we determine a base of $f^{-1}(V)$?

Comment: Are $U, W$ finite dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: @MarcoFlores Yes

Comment: I think it must be stated that $\;V\;$ is a *subspace* of $\;W\;$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a basis $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$ of the kernel of $f$ and vectors $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_k$ of $U$ such that $\{f(u_1),f(u_2),\dots,f(u_k)\}$ is a basis of $V\cap f(U)$.

Claim: $\{x_1,\dots,x_n,u_1,\dots,u_k\}$ is a basis for $f^{-1}(V)$.

First note that all those vectors belong to $f^{-1}(V)$. If $u\in f^{-1}(V)$, then
$$
f(u)=\beta_1f(u_1)+\dots+\beta_kf(u_k)
$$
Set $u'=\beta_1u_1+\dots+\beta_ku_k$ and note that $u-u'\in\ker f$, so…

Suppose
$$
\alpha_1x_1+\dots+\alpha_nx_n+\beta_1u_1+\dots+\beta_ku_k=0
$$
Then, applying $f$ we get that
$$
\beta_1f(u_1)+\dots+\beta_kf(u_k)=0
$$
so…

Comment: Why do such $u_1,u_2...,u_k$ exist?

Comment: @MarcoFlores Yes, you're right, I'll fix it.